# PHPStorm 8.0.2 Create New Project from Existing Files is grayed out

Tags: phpstorm

I cannot create new project from existing files since it is grayed out.

How to fix this?

I'm using PHPStorm 8.0.2 Build 139.732

[image: Create New Project from Existing Files is grayed out]

Comment: You might wanna ask this on the software SO. Don't think this is the right place. Weird behaviour anyhow.

Comment: Already did, just that this happened straight after update thought someone else might have asked them and solved it already. I should start a new quite large project and I'm in a bit hurry and support autoresponse stated support might be delayed due to holiday season until Janyary 12th.

Comment: I must admit that I'm quite curious about the solution, will follow this. Never encountered this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes -- it is disabled in 8.0.2 for some reason (bug).

It has been fixed already -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25902

Either wait for 8.0.3 to be released or use 8.0.3 **EAP build** -- http://eap.jetbrains.com/phpstorm

Comment: I have no experience about their release cycle, how long would you estimate release of 8.0.3 to take?

Comment: Sorry -- no real idea. Each release has different time intervals. But you can use EAP builds (it's not a n EAP for major version) -- it's stable.

Answer (score 5):

I experience the same behaviour.
What i do is just open some of my already working projects. 
Then I close that project and this option is not grayed out anymore.
I guess it is a bug.